# ATG Qualifer Service How to find qualifiers

Tags: java, atg, atg-dynamo, oracle-commerce, atg-droplet

For some promotions (like `spend y in x` and `get item discount`) OOTB qualifier service doesn't mark any commerce item as qualifier. And `evaluateQualifier()` method returns `boolean` instead of `List` type.

So in these particular scenarios: how to find the commerce items which acted as qualifier?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the loggingDebug in PricingManager and PricingEngine. It will shed some light on how the pricing is working and what qualifiers are used.

Comment: Have done the analysis, evaluateQualifier() of Qualifier service returns the list of valid qualifiers. It return List type 'for' promotions and boolean for 'always' and 'when' rule promotions .. In this case I don't get a list of qualifiers.. but I need a list of qualifiers for all types of promotions for custom logic implementation

Answer (score 0):

set evaluateTargetItemsFirst = false for your promo itemDescriptor in productCatalog, and then you will be able to find CommerceItems which acted as qualifier